# unclosed sql connection

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Suppose that i have an application that connects to a sql server, and this application connects to this server on the start of the application and close this connection on the exit of the application,i would like to know if any one can use this connection to connect to sql server

Comment: Can you elaborate on "any one". Are you saying programatically in code whether you can reuse the connection? Or are you referring to the act of someone actually using your credentials external to your application.

Comment: Only your own code can use the connection. What is the bigger picture?

Comment: programatically of course, i want to know if this connection can be hacked

Comment: I am not entirely sure why you would want to do this. Surely it would be better to open a connection as and when you need it and close it immediately after you have run your command. What do you gain by keeping a connection open when you are not using it?

Comment: @Mazen313 hacked *by what* ? Ultimately, someone with admin access on the PC can do all manner of evil things - for example, attach a low-level debugging tool and change core parts of memory. However, being hacked by an admin is **not** an interesting attack, as they are **already more powerful** than any system you can provide at the user level. This applies to ***any*** program running on that machine (nothing to do with .NET)

Comment: try it and you'll find a big difference in the performance of your application

Comment: @Marc Gravell hacked applies to " any program running on that machine"

Comment: @Mazen313 "try it and you'll find a big difference in the performance of your application" no, that is incorrect. Connection pooling means that you'll pretty much get back the same *underlying* connection. Creating, opening and closing `SqlConnection` instances is **not** the same as creating/opening/closing underlying connections. Use the pool. Keeping a connection open for this is a false optimization.

Comment: @Mazen313 I cannot parse your last comment (the one starting "hacked applies to"). Please re-phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single database connection will be restricted to the process that owns it. External applications will only have access to this connection via whatever API *your application* exposes.

However, **inside** that application, "connection pooling" means that different `SqlConnection` instances may all resolve to the same underlying *unmanaged* connection, as long as they don't overlap. More likely, repeated `SqlConnection` usage (different `SqlConnection` instances) will result in a *low number* of underlying connections.

Comment: @Mazen313 to define "safe", you first need to qualify *from what?*. So what do you mean by "safe" in this context? What are you trying to guard against?

Comment: safe from getting a sql attack

Comment: @Mazen313 sigh... what *kind* of SQL attack? If your application is badly written, then you could open yourself to SQL injection, but that is nothing to do with the connection lifetime. If somebody with admin access to the machine really wants to do nasty things, then... they probably can with enough skill - but that is true of **any** application, on **any** platform.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your question, however, connecting to a sql server on start and closing it on exit is a bad practice:

Assuming you just use a regular [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) .net will create its own [internal connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). Keeping it open the entire time could cause unwanted problems, for example by locking